# Shadow root SVG element null when querying but present in childNodes & elements tree

Tags: svg, shadow-dom, lottie

I am trying to target an SVG inside a shadow-root to override its styles and I am not able to do so.
I can see the SVG when navigating to it in devTools

[image]

and I can also see it inside its parent childrens & childNodes

[image]

However when I'm trying to access it I am always receiving null

I've tryied the following:

```
const lotties = document.querySelectorAll(".Menu__lottie");

lotties.forEach((lottie) => {
  const shadow = lottie.shadowRoot;
  const childNodes = Array.from(shadow.childNodes);
  const svg = childNodes[2].childNodes[1].childNodes[2];
  console.log(svg)
});
```

---

```
const lotties = document.querySelectorAll(".Menu__lottie");  
 
lotties.forEach((lottie) => {
   const shadow = lottie.shadowRoot;
   const svg = shadow.querySelector("svg")
   console.log(svg)
 });
```

Comment: even if you figure out how to access it the shadow tree is read-only. If you want to override styles, target the use instance with CSS or use CSS variables.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I manage to solve this by injecting a style sheet inside the shadow root & overriding the style properties by using !important.
  `const shadow = lottie.shadowRoot;
  var style = document.createElement("style");
  style.innerHTML = "svg{ width:200px !important }";
  shadow.appendChild(style);`

Comment: This is the only solution so far. Lottiefiles should provide a documentation regarding this.